# Laravel Authorization policy not getting called

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, policies

I'm having trouble getting one of my auth policies to run correctly, resulting in the authorization attempt always returning false. I'm even just forcing the function to return true for the sake of testing. I'm using Laravel 5.4, here's my policy function:

```
public function can_modify_or_delete(User $user, Comment $comment)
{
    return true;
}
```

in my `AuthServiceProvider.php` file I've added the `CommentPolicy` to my existing policy registrations.

```
protected $policies = [
    'App\Models\Post' => 'App\Policies\PostPolicy',
    'App\Models\Comment' => 'App\Policies\CommentPolicy',
];
```

oddly enough, that post policy has been working just fine. The comment one seems to either not be getting registered or not being called correctly.

In my routes:

```
Route::delete('/comments/{comment}', 'CommentsController@destroy');
```

and in the `CommentsController`

```
public function destroy(Request $request, Comment $comment)
{   
    $this->authorize('can_modify_or_delete', $comment);
    $comment->delete();

    return response(['status' => 'Comment deleted'], 200);
}
```

Unfortunately no matter what, that authorization check is returning false. Am I missing something? Checked pretty carefully for typos and couldn't find any. I also confirmed route model binding is working as intended so it's not a null resource issue. I tried `dd()` in the policy and it's not even getting called.

Comment: Is your route grouped under a middleware?

Comment: The controller uses the `auth:api` middleware. I confirmed I had an authenticated user by `dd()`ing it in the controller method right before the authorization is run.

Comment: is't output any error or just not working. Also, change true to false and see if any change happen

Answer (score 8):

Wow, so it actually was a typo on my end (typical!). In my `Comment` model I accidentally had a lowercase `models` in my namespace, ie it was:

```
namespace App\models;
```

when it should have been:

```
namespace App\Models;
```

This only caught me off guard because in my controller I had:

```
use App\Models\Comment;
```

and the `destroy()` method injects a comment, which was actually working fine, the comment was populating as normal. It seems policy registration paths must be much more exact than a `use` statement.

Comment: @Colin Its so weird. I had not included the use statement for my model in my AuthServiceProvider.php, never gave any errors but was not working...as soon as I included it...voila...you saved me an hour at least :)

Comment: i cannot believe im saying this but, this is EXACTLY the issue i had haha! my `Comment` model namespace had a lowercase m rather than uppercase ! go figure!

Comment: Haha I had a similar issue. Saw this answer and thought maybe my problem was something small like this. Auto-discovery wasn't working for me because I forgot to add the model the policy is for in the route's middleware. I.e I had:

   `...->middleware('can:update')`

Instead of:

    `...->middlware('can:update,model')`